# how to add a prefix to a domain name in django

Tags: django, url, dns, membership

I've seen another site with this functionality and would like to have it on my site as well, but I have no clue how to go about it.

Just say I had a membership site called www.mysite.com.

I would like to have it so that each member can go to his personal console by adding prefix to the domain, for example www.myconsole.mysite.com.

As I say I've seen this at another membership site I know.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: What you're looking for is resolving *subdomains* in `views.py`.
Check out [this](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tutorial.

Comment: You basically need dynamic subdomain resolver . This [Subdomain Middleware](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/) wills split the url and give you domain and subdomain in request as : `request.subdomain` and `request.domain` If You dont want a dynamic subdomain resolver then you probably should play with your DNS.